# Get user Login from User or Group field

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model

I have a list with User og Group field. I've retrieved item from it, now I need to get user's Login. By reading User or Group field I can get only user id and account name.
here's my code:

```
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var item = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        var assignedToVal = item.get_item('User Column');
        var userName = assignedToVal.get_lookupValue();
        var userId = assignedToVal.get_lookupId();
```

So now I have user id and name. How can I get a login?

Comment: So you are getting User's display name instead of user's login Name when accessing `assignedToVal.get_lookupValue();` ?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try getting User's information from User Information List:

```
function getUserInfo(userId,Success,Error)
{
   var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var userInfoList = context.get_web().get_siteUserInfoList();
   var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
   var viewXml = "<View> \
                    <Query> \
                       <Where> \
                           <Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Integer'>" + userId + "</Value></Eq> \
                       </Where>  \
                    </Query> \
                    <RowLimit>1</RowLimit> \
                  </View>";
   query.set_viewXml(viewXml);
   var items = userInfoList.getItems(query);
   context.load(items,'Include(Deleted,Department,EMail,FirstName,ID,IsActive,IsSiteAdmin,JobTitle,LastName,MobilePhone,Name,Notes,Office,Picture,SipAddress,UserName,WebSite,WorkPhone)');
   context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
       if(items.get_count() > 0) {
          var item = items.itemAt(0);
          Success(item.get_fieldValues());
       }
       else {
          Success(null);
       }   
     },
     Error
   );
}

//Usage
getUserInfo(userId,function(userInfo){
       console.log('User Login Name: ' + userInfo.UserName);

    },
    function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

Source:

[Get User via JavaScript Client Object Model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31457/get-user-via-javascript-client-object-model)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I need UserName property instead of login. Your code works just fine!