# JSOM Error in SharePoint Client Code When Retrieving User Object

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, jsom, client-side-rendering

Trying to figure out why I am getting this error with my code, am I missing a script reference, or is perhaps something wrong with the Context data grab section?

Error:

```
The property or field 'Email' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
```

Script references in Web Part Page:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientforms.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientpeoplepicker.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="autofill.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.RequestExecutor.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.runtime.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="SP.Debug.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="SP.Runtime.Debug.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
```

Code:

```
///////////////////Enable JSOM Intellisense for MS Visual Studio////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\clienttemplates.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\clientforms.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\clientpeoplepicker.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\autofill.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\sp.RequestExecutor.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\sp.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\sp.runtime.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\sp.core.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\sp.debug.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Projects\jquery\VsDoc\jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js" />
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
v_item = '';

$(
function () {
    if (typeof (_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') { _spBodyOnLoadWrapper(); }
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getDivision_Chief_User, "sp.js");
});

function getDivision_Chief_User() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var web = clientContext.get_web();

    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('myTestList'); 

    v_item = list.getItemById(1);

    clientContext.load(v_item);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
}
function onSuccess(sender, args) {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var userName = v_item.get_item('myPersonLookUpField').get_lookupValue();
    var user = web.ensureUser(userName);

    //ERROR HAPPENS HERE WHEN DEBUGING IN BROWSER

    var email = user.get_email();
    var loginName = user.get_loginName();
    var v_Id = user.get_id();
    var v_Title = user.get_title();

    alert('The Display Name of the user is ' + email);
    alert('The Account Name of the user is ' + loginName);
    alert('The email address of the user is ' + v_Id);
    alert('The User Title is ' + v_Title);

    //$("#h_ValueWritter").html(v_commentsTemp);


}
function onFailure(sender, args) {

    console.log('Failure!');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the code modified as below:

```
    ///////////////////Enable JSOM Intellisense for MS Visual Studio////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\clienttemplates.js" />
    /// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\clientforms.js" />
    /// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\clientpeoplepicker.js" />
    /// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\autofill.js" />
    /// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\sp.RequestExecutor.js" />
    /// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\sp.js" />
    /// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\sp.runtime.js" />
    /// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\sp.core.js" />
    /// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\sp.debug.js" />
    /// <reference path="C:\Projects\jquery\VsDoc\jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js" />
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    v_item = '';
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function(){
            SP.SOD.registerSod("sp.userprofiles.js", SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl("sp.userprofiles.js"));
            SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.userprofiles.js", "SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager", getDivision_Chief_User);
    });

    function getDivision_Chief_User() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var web = clientContext.get_web();

        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('myTestList'); 

        v_item = list.getItemById(1);

        clientContext.load(v_item,"Include(Title,myPersonLookUpField)"); //add the column internal name

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
    }
    function onSuccess(sender, args) {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var userName = v_item.get_item('myPersonLookUpField').get_lookupValue();
        var user = web.ensureUser(userName);
        context.load(user);
        context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
       var email = user.get_email();
        var loginName = user.get_loginName();
        var v_Id = user.get_id();
        var v_Title = user.get_title();

        alert('The Display Name of the user is ' + email);
        alert('The Account Name of the user is ' + loginName);
        alert('The email address of the user is ' + v_Id);
        alert('The User Title is ' + v_Title);

        //$("#h_ValueWritter").html(v_commentsTemp);  

},
function(sender, args){

  alert(args.get_message());

});

    }
    function onFailure(sender, args) {

        console.log('Failure!');
    }
```

Comment: Getting the following error at below line of code: 

The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

var userName = v_item.get_item('myPersonLookUpField').get_lookupValue();

Comment: have modified it now. It will include the custom column in context.load

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is happening because you have to load the user object before you can use it.  So for instance, after your lines:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var userName = v_item.get_item('myPersonLookUpField').get_lookupValue();
var user = web.ensureUser(userName);
```

you would then need to do:

```
context.load(user);
context.executeQueryAsync(onSecondSuccess, onFailure);
```

**before** you can work with the `user` object:

```
var email = user.get_email();
var loginName = user.get_loginName();
var v_Id = user.get_id();
var v_Title = user.get_title();
```

Comment: Tried that and still getting same error as the original error 

    The property or field 'Email' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.